# Different image size OpenCV stereoCalibrate

Tags: opencv

I have two cameras with different resolutions but stereoCalibrate functions has only one option for imagesize.

If I understand correctly stereoCalibrate computes rigid transformation matrix from cam1 to cam2. If that is true then which camera size should I use as input to the function stereoCalibrate?

Answer (score 4):

The `imageSize` parameter is used only to initialize intrinsic camera matrices.

I suggest to calibrate each camera independently using [`cv::calibrateCamera()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera) and so get the camera matrices and distortion coefficients for each camera. And then estimate the transformation between the camera coordinate systems (rotation `R` and translation `t`) using [`cv::stereoCalibrate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate) with flags `CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` enabled (with the pre-estimated camera matrices and distortion coefficients).

And so the `imageSize` parameter doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I have done the same, however the RMS error reported by cv::stereoCalibrate() function was high( 0.57) so I was wondering if that was due to the image size. Reproj error for Cam1 and Cam2 are 0.26 and 0.22 respectively. I tried stereo calibration from Matlab, the  RMS error reported there was 0.23. Any idea why RMS error is high in case of OpenCV or do you have any other suggestions to improve accuracy. I use the 7x19 asymmetric pattern pasted on a flat glass plate.

Comment: I think your final reprojection error is low enough (0.57 px can be considered as subpixel accuracy). BTW you can play with the parameter `term_crit` or try to use a different (i.e. chessboard) pattern.